# Rewriting a Stored Procedure to return the first elements by group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns the first element of each group, but I'm doing it with a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    id,
    date, 
    data
    (select top 1
         id,
         date,
         data
    from table as t2
    where t2.id = t1.id
    order by t2.date) as first
from table t1;
```

The goal is to return all the data, but also the first item with each row.

How can I rewrite this query so it doesn't scan the entire table N times for N records in the table?

Comment: That query won't run as is.  Start by supplying sample data and expected results.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I echo the points above, but this sounds like you are probably looking for a solution that would be suited to `cross apply` or `outer apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with a CTE that gets only the first row for each `id` and then join your main query to the CTE on `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an `outer apply` scenario:

```
select 
    t1.id,
    t1.date, 
    t1.data,
   first.id,
   first.[date],
   first.data
from table t1
outer apply (
    select top 1
         t2.id,
         t2.date,
         t2.data
    from table as t2
    where t2.id = t1.id
    order by t2.date) as first;
```

The `first` aliases will be `null` if the `id` fields don't match.